# How do I control my neopixel Arduino lights via a html website

Tags: html, arduino, arduino-esp8266, neopixel

I am fairly new to programming Arduino's, I have created a Arduino script using esp8266 to take a query from its up and performing a command. This works and I can type in to my browser 192.168.1.66/?code=r0-50 which turns on all the leds numbered 0-50 red. I can also type /?code=g23 an it will turn the 23rd led on. I was wondering if there was any way to control this by clicking buttons on a Web page?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. You question is too broad. Please provide some code samples which you tried and minimum reproducible code for debugging

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there is a http server running on your device but if you want to put the command you mentioned onto another server or html file in your network, you can use something like

```html
<html>
<a href="192.168.1.66/?code=r0-50"><img src="mybutton.png" /></a>
</html>
```